# Regex to match the hour portion of a time zone caption string

Tags: regex, powershell, timezone

I'm querying remote servers for their timezone using PowerShell.

-edit: To clarify, and I want to apologize up front for falling down the XY pitfall.  I've got a list of servers that are pending reboot.  In my list, I've got the maintenance window (example KWA - SRV - Patching - Prod - Sun 2:00) which is listed in Local Time.  In the example, its (UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney.  Here is where I got lost, I was looking for a method using PowerShell to grab the maintenance window (Sun 2:00) plus the TimeZone from the server which would be used to generate the local time that server can be restarted at.

`gwmi -Class win32_timezone` which returns Caption `(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)` and `(UTC+10:00) Canberra, Melbourne, Sydney`

I've been looking around for some regex to grab just the non-zero digit, in the above example I'd need to return 5 and 10.  Every example I've found is not PowerShell specific so I'm having a tough time making the examples work in PowerShell.  The reason for this regex is to use `Get-Date` and add hours to get the correct remote timezone time.

My attempts, in the PowerShell console.  Can someone help me with this regex?

```
"(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)" -replace '[^\p{Nd}]'

0600
```

Comment: This smells like [an XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/201534) to me.  What are you actually trying to *do* here?  If you need the time zone bias, then just get it directly from the `Bias` property.  Don't extract it from `Caption` with a regex.  (See [the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394498.aspx) for examples).

Comment: Also make sure you recognize that the offset in the caption string is just the *standard* offset.  It will not change to reflect DST.

Comment: Apologies, the goal of this question is to provide a time (in PST) that would be converted to the local timezone.  For example, a reboot at 6pm Eastern occurs at 3pm Pacific.  Additionally, in DST the local timezone (Pacific) would also change and satisfy the DST change, or am I incorrect in this thinking?

Answer (score 1):

You are not looking to match non-zero digits. If you replaced all the zeros you would only get 1 from the 10 you expect for output.

You are trying to match the *hour* portion. I would like to think you might be able to get this another way but one regex that you could use would be to match the whole time but capture the hour in a group

```
(gwmi -Class win32_timezone).Caption -match "(\d{2}):\d{2}"
$matches[1]
```

That would return 05 and 10 for those two examples. Cast as `[int]` if you need those values to be truly numbers.

Now you would have an issue if you plan on using this for time manipulation as the number alone does not give you the offset. You need to match the sign as well.

```
(gwmi -Class win32_timezone).Caption -match "(.\d{2}):\d{2}"
[int]$matches[1]
```

Matching the number and the preceding character would get us the sign. Casting to `[int]` would get -5 and 10 with the examples.

Answer (score 1):

Using `-replace`:

```
'(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)' -replace '\(UTC-(\d\d).+','$1' -as [int]
```

Comment: Some of the results have GMT instead of UTC.  I've abandoned this approach for simply matching the server names and manually verifying the time zone then simply statically coding the appropriate hour offset.  Also, I found some servers without a TimeZone set PLUS one or two set incorrectly.

Comment: First rule of regex: "Know your data."